# Best way to access the database in Android

Tags: android, database

I was wondering what the best way to access a database is in Android.
I currently have the following:

```
Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<StudentProfile> students = db.getAllStudents();
    }*/

    //db.getAllStudents();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is currently at the end of the onCreate method, however, every time i open the project it recalls the databse, so I've ended up with every thing being repeated over and over again, which isn't what i need.

Any tips or suggestions to get this working right would be much appreicated!

Thanks :)

Comment: `CursorLoader. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) an example,

Comment: @Blackbelt - I am using the Cursor in my databaseHandler class:

    `public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }`

How could I go about using the Loader and Adaptor? and where would I use it?

Comment: which onCreate() method is this in?

Comment: @nPn - my mainActivity onCreate method at the moment, it'll probably need moved to a new class at some point though

Comment: Have you thought about moving that code to a service, or even the onCreate of your Application class?  If you move it to one of those places you would need some observer on the database to watch for changes and then reload it.

Comment: I'm not really quite sure what you mean...?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "This is currently at the end of the onCreate method, however, every time i open the project it recalls the databse, so I've ended up with every thing being repeated over and over again, which isn't what i need".

What do you need?

It is normal for code inside the onCreate method to run once for every project opening. You should see the log once for every opening.

If you want to access the data once after opening the project several times, maybe you should have a button to query the list.

Comment: I wasn't really sure if that specific piece needed to be in that method is all. 
Thanks for the suggestion. 
In this case, I am using a list menu that will allow the user to select the student information that they want to view - much like the layout of whatsapp or snapchat - The end users of my project don't want a button, they just want their list populated on login.

Comment: Sounds like what you have is correct.  Every time somebody logs in they need the latest data.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Okay, good stuff.
Not really, every time the application is opened, the data is accessed, so all of the data that was there previously is showing up too, so it's showing duplicates of the data. I'm looking for a way to stop that from happening (Sorry if my question wasn't clear!)

Comment: You should not get duplicates if you are querying the data fresh each time.  Where is ArrayofName? Are there duplicates in that? Is it being written to?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought. 
ArrayOfName is in my DatabaseHandler and MainActivity classes... i'm not sure how to check it? Yes, in the handler i have the following: 
`String name = cursor.getString(1) +" "+ cursor.getString(2);
                MainActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);`

Comment: I am not sure how you handle the data. I assume you are you using sqlite3 to store the data. If you are, is the section of code you wrote after the data has been retrieved from the database, that would make some sense where you are displaying the array in other bits of you code.

Comment: ...continuing.. The code section you had in your question should always get fresh data from the database and you should only write to the database when you have a new student to add.

Comment: Yes, i am using sqlite3 (not that i have a clue how to actually use it properly). I don't even know how to view the data that i have..

Comment: You have basic problems. You better lean how to view sqlite3 data. Google "viewing database data through sqlite3". I use:

Comment: ... Continuing.. run cmd
cd <android_tools>
adb shell
cd data
cd data
cd <your package>
cd databases
ls   # check for database existence (<your database>.db)
sqlite3 <your database>.db
.dump